# python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

whats the regular expression in python for any string without the char '/'. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know python's flavor of regex, but I can only imagine it would look something like this:

```
^[^/]*$
```

Answer (score 8):

No need for regular expressions

```
>>> s = 'asdf'
>>> '/' in s
False
>>> s = 'asd/asdf'
>>> '/' in s
True
```